# Как проверить что написано в определенной строке string

Tags: c#, unity3d, строки

У меня есть string и мне нужно проверить, что в нем написано. Проблема в том, что у меня получается проверить, но не с первой строчки. Т.е. он проверяет по порядку в скрипте.

```html
    public void CheckText()
    {
        b = text.text;
        if (b.IndexOf("a") > -1)
        {
            Debug.Log("a");
        }
        if (b.IndexOf("b") > -1)
        {
            Debug.Log("b");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `мне нужно проверить, что в нем написано` - что это значит? Можете в деталях вашу задачу написать и почему решение ваше не подходит?

Comment: Допустим, у меня на второй строчке A, а на второй B. Он выведет первой а, а второй B. Нужно, чтобы он  проверил каждую строчку на A и B

Comment: Примеры текста и результата приведите. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: IndexOf в вашем случае ищет первую букву в string, где string - весь текст. Вам надо разбить текст на строчки и пройтись по каждой?

Comment: `if (b.IndexOf("a") > -1 && b.IndexOf("b") > -1)`?

Comment: @aepot мне нужно проверить каждую строчку на наличия слов, которые прописаны в скрипте

Comment: @aepot можете показать как разбить текст на строчки и проверить каждую

Comment: `string[] lines = text.text.Split(Environment.NewLine);` или если так не компилируется, то `string[] lines = text.text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` и пройтись циклом по строкам `foreach(string line in lines) { ...ваш код... }`, уж цикл по массиву то вы сможете :)

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал через Split, только Environment не работает